# Obtain post param from success url in Paumoney integration

Tags: javascript, angular, payment-gateway, payumoney

I have integrated payumoney payment gateway in angular 2 but when payumoney redirect to success url that time how can I get the params like transaction id and all other param?

what shall i right in the success url to get the response param by payumoney? I'm not able to see param in url like get url.

```
<form #f method="post" id="payu-payment-form" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment">
      <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="{{hash}}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{marchentKey}}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="{{txnid}}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{amount}}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="{{productinfo}}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="{{firstname}}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{email}}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="{{phone}}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="surl" value="http://example.net/payment"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="http://example.com/payment"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="" />
      <button class="" type="submit" (click)="f.submit()" value="submit" formtarget="_blank" >Buy</button>
      </form>
```

Obtain post param from url in angular 2?

Comment: *i have no idea how to obtain post param from url?* By reading the manual?

Comment: How on earth did this get 4 upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

When payment success. PayU money redirects to success url with POST method. You cannot handle POST method using javascript. you need a backend. So please set success url to a backend server, from there handle the post request and redirect your correct front end url

Answer (score 0):

You can get the params in the response page as follow:

1. Import ActivatedRoute `import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router`
2. Add it to the constructor `constructor(private r: ActivatedRoute) {}`
3. Subscribe to the route queryParams and capture the params in the response if available

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
       this.r.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
          var transactionState =  params['transactionState'] || 'None';
           ...
       });
   };
   ```

For reference check Angular's [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular is a javascript framework, you can not handle POST requests on Angular side. Payment Gateway POST response needs to be handled at the server side API. I came across a nice article on this. It might help you,

https://www.devglan.com/angular/payumoney-integration-angular